# Celery+Django -- How to log non-task module

Tags: python, django, celery

Currently, my Django+Docker-Compose project is able to use Celery to make the main uploading function, `insertIntoDatabase`, an asynchronous task that properly runs in the background. I run Celery using a Docker container named `worker`, and I can see its logs in the console just fine. However, the logging that usually worked in `insertIntoDatabase` now no longer happens.

Uploading begins in `views.py`:

```
from .tasks import db_ins_task
...
db_ins_task.delay(datapoints, user, description) # datapoints is a list of dictionaries, user and description are simple strings
```

And the task is defined as such in `tasks.py`:

```
@app.task()
def db_ins_task(datapoints, user, description):
    from utils.db.databaseinserter import insertIntoDatabase
    insertIntoDatabase(datapoints, user, description)
```

So in `databaseinserter.py`, the following logging no longer works:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp.databaseinserter')
...
def insertIntoDatabase(datapoints, user, description):
    # do the database insertion work
    ...
    logger.info("This upload took %.3g seconds", elapsed_time)
```

The info log at the end is supposed to go to a log file that I configured in `settings.py`. Now that `insertIntoDatabase` is called from a task rather than directly, info logs of this sort no longer appear in the proper log file. All other logging that existed in my project still works fine. What should I do to make the logging work again?

For further reference, here is part of `celery.py` in a separate app named `taskman`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig
from celery import Celery, Task

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('myproj')
class CeleryConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'taskman'
    verbose_name = 'Celery Config'

    def ready(self):
        app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
        app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

And here is the pertinent part of the logging settings in `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers' = {
    ...
        'dbinsfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'maxBytes':LOG_LIMIT,
            'backupCount':10,
            'filename':'logs/insvals.log',
            'formatter':'values',
        },
    ...

    },
    'formatters' = {
    ...
        'values': {
            'format':'>>> [%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
            'datefmt':"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    ...
    },
    'loggers' = {
    ...
        'myapp.databaseinserter': {
            'handlers':['dbinsfile'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'propagate':False,
        },
    ...
    }
}
```

***EDIT:*** I think the issue is that Celery seems to be hijacking the root level logger, or something like that. I've already tried `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False` but it didn't change anything, unfortunately. I've also tried adding the following to `settings.py`:

```
from celery.signals import setup_logging
@setup_logging.connect
def logging_prevent_celery_hijack(loglevel, logfile, format, colorize, **kwargs):
    import logging.config
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

following the Celery docs on signals and logging, but this seemed to have no effect either.

Comment: "no longer works" Meaning what? If the code is called from your Django project (e.g. in a view) it works but if called from a task, then it does not work? How is logging configured in your workers?

Comment: "no longer works" meaning that the logging statements I put in `insertIntoDatabase` are no longer happening. I used to call the function directly but now I call the task which calls the function. All logging was configured in `settings.py` in a manner following the Django documentation.

Comment: Right, so how would I take care of that in the Celery app? I have `celery.py` in an app named `taskman` and there I set it to use my Django settings, which is currently working. What do I need to do in addition so that the worker can basically do the same logging that the original function did?

Comment: I find the use of an `AppConfig` instance that calls the configuration functions of Celery to be unusual. I've always had the `app.config_from_object()` and `app.autodiscover_tasks()` in the topmost scope of my `celery.py`. But I cannot put my finger on what would be wrong exactly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

From [the official document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging):

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

If the `logger.xxxx()` is called inside a function by a Celery worker, the `logger` configured by Celery will be used; otherwise, it will be the one configured manually. The behavior is irrelevant to where the function belongs.